# ComponentMeasurements properties

Tags: image-processing

How do the `ComponentMeasurements` function computed `" Area"` and `"Length"` properties relate to the `"Count"` property in terms of pixels  ?

Answer (score 3):

In nuce; while both `"Count"` and `"Area"` can be both considered as metrics for the area covered by an object in a given black and white image (i.e. Bit type), they do not account for it in the same way.

`"Count"` literally and simply counts the number of pixels forming the object sensu stricto.

`“Area”` counts the same pixels but score them according to their relative localization to each other based on some 2*2 neighborhood rules.  In this case, I believe one should not disable the `CornerNeighbors` option of `ComponentMeasurements` which is by default True.

For an exhaustive answer please follow the link below:

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/963892

Comment: Thank you for reporting on that answer. Since links are likely to age and break, however, it would be welcome if you could briefly summarize the answer you linked to.